# Bash Script for PHP Lint always returning 0

Tags: git, bash, phplint

**EDIT: THIS WORKS NOW.  I copied this into a my CentOS box and it works like a charm.  I was testing this script on Windows and it only returns 0 (even when PHP LINT gives an error)**

This bash script is supposed to perform a PHP LINT CHECKER.  No matter which files I feed the `php -l`, it always returns 0 (success).  I have even purposely cause one of my files to have a syntax error (missing semicolon), but it still returns 0.

For testing purposes, I have `php -l` stored in a variable $STUFF and have it return `what` if the return status of `php -l` is 0

I have tried numerous other methods but `php -l` keeps returning 0 (success)

```
#!/bin/bash

DIFF_FILES=$(git diff --cached --name-status --diff-filter=AM | awk '{print $2}')

function syntaxChecker() {
    for files in $DIFF_FILES; do
        STUFF=$(/c/PHP/php -l $files)
        if [ $STUFF -eq 0 ]; then
            echo 'what'
        fi
done
}

syntaxChecker
```

Answer (score 1):

> For testing purposes, I have `php -l` stored in a variable $STUFF and have it return `what` if the return status of `php -l` is 0

That's not what your code says. Your code stores the *output* of `php -l` and then compares that with 0; the return status of a command is stored in `$?`. And as always you can check for a non-zero return status directly in `if`.

```
if php -l ...
```

Comment: This does not work properly.. `if [ "/c/PHP/php -l $files" -eq 0 ];` because an integer expression is expected.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you decided to make up your own syntax instead of using the one in the answer?

Comment: How am I making up my own syntax? php is not in my $PATH, so I am calling out the absolute path of PHP and then using `php -l` on the list of files that I have

Comment: Neither the `[` command nor the `[[` command expect to be passed another command.

Comment: `for files in $DIFF_FILES; do
  /c/PHP/php -l $files`
Still returning all 0's